# Is Google OneTap compatible with Google APIs?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

I'm trying to create an android app that will access the user's Google Calendar, thereby needing access to the Google Calendar API.

To do so, I need to authenticate the user. As far as I know there are two different ways of doing so, Google's new OneTap API or with the legacy Google Sign-in API. This is my first time working with Google APi's and I'm a bit confused, I integrated OneTap in my project but I don't really understand where / how to continue.

I was able to integrate OneTap successfully and getting an idToken, but I read somewhere that the OAuth consent screen that ultimately allows me to access Google API's can only be triggered through the old legacy google sign on API, can anyone point me in the right direction? Would be super grateful!

Comment: Googles new web identity splits signin and oauth.   This is the [authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/additional-scopes) system for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself after reaching someone working on OneTap: getting Authorization Tokens through OAuth is **currently NOT supported** but from what I have heard there is a discussion on adding it in the future.

Use the legacy Google Sign-in API, this will allow you to clarify OAuth scopes quite easily. I'm guessing that support for OneTap Auth is likely coming in the near future.

[Legacy API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

I will try to update this thread when support is added.